# Java z-ordering in a fake 3D plane?

Tags: java, java-3d, z-order

I am implementing a project like Notch's "breaking the tower", in Java.
I have it mostly written, but I'm having difficulty with z-order.

When the objects "rotate" around the center they still draw on top of each other badly.  For example a tree in the background might draw on top of a tree "in front" of it.

can anyone suggest an algorithm that would help me solve the problem?
 ...or maybe help explain the full concept of z-ordering or even possibly give another solution.

thanks

Comment: Google "Painter's Algorithm". What you want to do is always paint from back to front. So, given an array of objects to paint, each with a z-order defined, sort the array from lowest to highest z-order, then paint the objects in the order they are found in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to de resumes to making an array with the z-coordinates, sorting the array, and then translating objects to their place. For example:

```
TransformGroup translate(Node node,Vector3f vector){

    Transform3D transform3D = new Transform3D();
    transform3D.setTranslation(vector);
    TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    transformGroup.setTransform(transform3D);
    transformGroup.addChild(node);
    return transformGroup;
}    
for(int i=0;vec[i];i++)
 translate(Your_Object,new Vector3f(x,y,vec[i]);
//do this while you still have elements in your vector. 
//you may want to set a value, let's say 2500 that  indicates that you ran out of objects
//in that case, you will have for(int i=0;vec[i]!=2500;i++)
```

So, this way, your objects should be one in front of another rather then stack one on top of the other.

Hope it helps,
Mike